# I am looking for an application to host web services on FreeBSD

Tags: linux, web-services, unix, web, freebsd

My boss has asked me to look into applications to host web services on our FreeBSD machine.  Previously I have only used visual studios to do web services so I am wondering what is the best applications on there to host them on in a unix environment?

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Just to be clear, I am talking about something like this: http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/  I am just not familiar with what is the most popular/most stable ect. on the unix side of things.

Comment: This is off-topic for SO; please read the [FAQ] and [Ask].

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the application you want to host.
There are several ways to solve your task:

1. Use normal web-server (e.g. Apache, Nginx and so on)
2. Use specialized software with innate web-server capabilities (e.g. Twisted, Node.JS and so on).

You need to be more concrete to get concreter answer :)

Comment: love the word concreter!